# Passing data in Flask across requests

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to figure out the best way to pass data between Flask requests when using redirect. Here is some of my code first,

**models**

```
class Customer(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'customers'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
first_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
last_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
phone_number = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True)
address = db.Column(db.Text)
last_order = db.Column(db.Text)
send_email = db.Column(db.Boolean)

def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, address,
             last_order, send_email):
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.email = email
    self.phone_number = phone_number
    self.address = address
    self.last_order = last_order
    self.send_email = send_email

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Customer {} {}>'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

**views**

```
blueprint = Blueprint('customer', __name__, url_prefix='/customer')


@blueprint.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def home():
    """Logged-in user homepage"""
    error = None
    form = CustomerSearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        phone_number = form.phone_number.data
        customer = Customer.query.filter_by(phone_number=phone_number).first()
        if customer:
            return redirect(url_for('customer.customer', customer_id=customer.id))
        else:
            error = 'Customer with phone number {} not found'.format(phone_number)
    form.phone_number.data = ''
    return render_template('customer/index.html', form=form, error=error)


@blueprint.route('/<int:customer_id>', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def customer(customer_id):
    """Get customer by id"""
    customer = Customer.query.get(customer_id)
    return render_template('customer/customer.html', customer=customer, form=form)
```

So, write now, when I add a customer and I pass the id to the view customer with redirect(url_for('customer.customer')), I have to search for the customer again in the database and then render my template. I wanted help in determining if this is a correct/good approach? I know I cannot use **g** because doing redirect means a new request and hence **g** will not persist.

I can use **session** but then I found out that I have to do something like

```
session['customer'] = customer
```

where customer is an instance of Customer model, I will have a write a custom JsonEncoder where I will define how to encode the customer instance ([Fixing the class to enable object storing in Flask session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035878/fixing-the-class-to-enable-object-storing-in-flask-session)).

So, is it better to retrieve customer from database again using provided customer id or store customer object in **session** (using the custom JsonEncoder) or is there another better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the correct approach. Querying twice isn't so expensive.

You can also try [Message Flashing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/flashing/) for showing something like error with redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you should pass the objects across requests or do a new query depends on your integrity requirements.

If your business logic can't affort stale data, then do a query, caz database is the single state of truth, and the transaction can save you lots of troubles.

Otherwise, you can pass around data. And there are several ways:

```
1. A session object server side, which store inside memcached or something.
2. Cookies, which is not used that much I guess.
3. JWT, which I believe is the right approach.
```

[jwt](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

Comment: How would I use a JWT token? I want to pass data from one view to another view (via redirect)

Comment: ok, does that i mean i still have to write a custom JsonEncoder to define how to encode my customer instance?

Comment: https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt Check out the document, You can pass a dict object to it.